# What are the main advantages of using a Singleton class for a "utility" class?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've seen many references to "Singleton" and have seen them used for "utility" functions such as common validations, conversions, etc.   Assuming there's no need to reference "self", is there any advantage of using a singleton, as opposed to simply implement the utility class with class methods and optional static variables?  Style? Performance? Concurrency?

In other words, instead of calling foo through a MySingleton instance:

```
BOOL b = [[MySingleton sharedInstance] foo:xyz];
```

one could call foo through MyUtility's class method:

```
BOOL b = [[MyUtility class] foo:xyz];
```

The implementation of either class is implied and I shall forgo listing them if that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are no advantages other than that *you assume no references to self*. And by 'you' I don't mean your implementation of `MyUtility`, I mean those classes that call `MyUtility` — in other words you end up investing knowledge of the implementation of `MyUtility` into other classes, contrary to usual object-oriented principles.

That said, the same argument runs the other way. If you assume that there's an instance then `MyUtility` is required to act as an instance. If you call class methods then it can internally pass those to a singleton instance.

However because instances are the norm rather than the exception it's stylistically less presumptive to expect to talk to an instance.

Comment: So your vote is on style. Thanks. BTW, I forgot another consideration - flexibility.  Singletons provide the flexibility should the need arises for shared instance variable.  PS. I don't understand your point regarding the use of 'self' by other classes that use MyUtility though.

Comment: Style and flexibility. Instances are the norm; assuming the internal implementation of another class doesn't conform to the norm is contrary to object-oriented principles and puts that class in a syntactically displeasing position if it wants an instance.